# Blocking list operations in JRedis

Tags: redis

Does JRedis support the blocking list operations (BRPOP and/or BLPOP) ?

I have a simple producer / consumer setup using a Redis list as a queue, and I would like to avoid polling the queue...

I'm using Redis 1.3.14 (a.k.a. 2.0.0 RC1) and I tried both jredis 1.0 
RC1 and the latest from the git master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. 1.2.n RC2 is due to be out very shortly and support for 1.3.n (Redis 2.0) is the immediate next major updates.  This should support everything but the Monitor command.  So, jredis 1.0 will get the blocking semantics after JRedis 2.0 support for the same is released.

(API RFC was posted to jredis google group, so speak up if you have strong opinions.)

Master branch on github repo always tracks redis repo.
1.2.n branch is the 1.2.n client.  RC1 release was a couple of months ago, so if you want the latest, pull from 1.2.n.